# Pandas Vectorization with Function on Parts of Column

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2, 3], [5,7,8], [2,5,4]])
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  5  7  8
2  2  5  4
```

I then have a function that adds 5 to a number called `add5`. I'm trying to create a new column in `df1` that adds 5 to all the numbers in column 2 that are greater than 3. I want to use vectorization not apply as this concept is going to be expanded to a dataset with hundreds of thousands of entries and speed will be important. I can do it without the greater than 3 constraint like this:

```
df1['3'] = add5(df1[2])
```

But my goal is to do something like this:

```
df1['3'] = add5(df1[2]) if df1[2] > 3
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Pandas, a function applied explicitly to each row typically cannot be vectorised. Even implicit loops such as [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) will likely be inefficient. Instead, you should use true vectorised operations, which lean heavily on NumPy in both functionality and syntax.

In this case, you can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1[3] = np.where(df1[2] > 3, df1[2] + 5, df1[2])
```

Alternatively, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) in a couple of steps:

```
df1[3] = df1[2]
df1.loc[df1[2] > 3, 3] = df1[2] + 5
```

In each case, the term `df1[2] > 3` creates a Boolean series, which is then used to mask another series.

Result:

```
print(df1)

   0  1  2   3
0  1  2  3   3
1  5  7  8  13
2  2  5  4   9
```

Comment: So I'm hoping to expand this concept to functions that are a lot more complex than simply adding 5. Is it possible to do something like np.where(df1[2] > 3, add5(df1[2]), df1[2])?

Comment: @JSolomonCulp, If it's a numeric function, it's *highly* likely you can vectorise it. So, in short, I advise against hypothetical judgements. If you have a complex algorithm which you are struggling to vectorise, it might be a good question [to ask separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the help, np.where will definitely be helpful